# Create a form with 1 button linking to a download and a email

Tags: html, css

Hello i was just wondering if anyone knows a way to link a form button on submit to open a pdf as well as send a email to the admin email address I want it to sent to so I can see who got the pdf?
Here is my code:

```
<div>
<form action="https://www.the-grey-elephant.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/TGE-Ebook-8-Ways_Final.pdf" target="_blank">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email..">

  <label for="automation">Are You Running Esko's Automation Engine?</label>
  <select id="automation" name="automation">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="GET IT">
</form>
```

Comment: try to use <button></button> to instead <input type="submit" value="GET IT">, and change form action into your PHP(e.x. Record.php) to solve the problem. To open the pdf, using button onclick.

Answer (score 1):

## Important Note

**Anyone can open the PDF with the link! So, if you choose the solution you mentioned in your question, there is a possibility that people who did not receive the email may also see your PDF.**

---

### Answer for question (need using PHP)

As a first step, we call a background program, such as PHP, which will handle the operation. This is because sending the email is not handled by the client, but by the web server.

```html
<form action="http://localhost/send-email.php" type="POST">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email..">

  <label for="automation">Are You Running Esko's Automation Engine?</label>
  <select id="automation" name="automation">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="GET IT">
</form>
```

So we pass the client's data to our "send-email.php" file via a POST request.

In this PHP file, I declare for you the sending of an email using the basic PHP command, `mail()`.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Can use safe email sender PHP libary:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

After this, I redirect the user to the PDF link using the `header()` function.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

send-mail.php:

```php
<?php
// 1.) Send email
// TODO: make email sending method
// - example: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example

// 2.) Redirect the user to PDF file
header('Location: https://www.the-grey-elephant.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/TGE-Ebook-8-Ways_Final.pdf');
?>
```

### Summary

**I noticed that you did not specify PHP as a topic, which is why I explained in more detail that the question is more complicated than you might have initially thought!**

1.) The user fills out the form and clicks on the button.

2.) As a result, the form is sent to the ./send-email.php file (i.e. to the server).

3.) The server executes the sending of the email to the administrator (due to the execution of the send-email.php file).

4.) The server redirects the user to the PDF file link (due to the execution of the send-email.php file).

Therefore, after the email has been sent, we redirect the user to the PDF file.

What does this look like from the user's perspective?

1.) As a user, I fill out the form and click on the button.

2.) The PDF file loaded in my browser.